# Is there a function that shuffles certain portion of both row and column of a numpy matrix in python?

Tags: python-3.x, shuffle

I have a 2D matrix. I want to shuffle last few columns and rows associated with those columns.

I tried using np.random.shuffle but it only shuffles the column, not rows.

```py
def randomize_the_data(original_matrix, reordering_sz):
    new_matrix = np.transpose(original_matrix)
    np.random.shuffle(new_matrix[reordering_sz:])
    shuffled_matrix = np.transpose(new_matrix)
    print(shuffled_matrix)

a = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
print(a)
print()
randomize_the_data(a, 2)
```

My original matrix is this:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
```

I am getting this.

```
[[ 0  1  3  4  2]
 [ 5  6  8  9  7]
 [10 11 13 14 12]
 [15 16 18 19 17]]
```

But I want something like this.

```
[[ 0  1  3  2  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 14 12 13]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
```

Another example would be:

```
Original =

   -1.3702    0.3341   -1.2926   -1.4690   -0.0843
    0.0170    0.0332   -0.1189   -0.0234   -0.0398
   -0.1755    0.2182   -0.0563   -0.1633    0.1081
   -0.0423   -0.0611   -0.8568    0.0184   -0.8866


Randomized =

   -1.3702    0.3341   -0.0843   -1.2926   -1.4690
    0.0170    0.0332   -0.0398   -0.0234   -0.1189
   -0.1755    0.2182   -0.0563    0.1081   -0.1633
   -0.0423   -0.0611    0.0184   -0.8866   -0.8568
```

Comment: Could you more clearly define how you want these matrices shuffled? Do you actually want duplicate items in the final matrix (see `2`)?

Comment: Yes! I want the same items but in another cell. Just randomly distributed.

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that mistake. It was a typing mistake!

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want everything outside of the upperleft 2x2 matrix shuffled around? Would the following shuffle be acceptable: [[ 0  1  3  10  19]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [2 11 14 12 13]
 [4 16 17 18 15]]

Comment: Nope! 1st 2 columns should be fixed as it is. I just want to reorder the number of columns that is given as input and the rows associated with those columns.

Comment: Ok, "the rows associated with those columns" is a phrase I don't quite understand. It looks to me like you want the numbers in the last 3 columns shuffled but to have them stay in the same row they started in.  I cannot tell the difference between what you have now and what you want.

Comment: Sorry about that! Let me try again!
As you can see when I am trying to shuffle the column is shifting. For example [3, 8, 13, 18] is in the same column before and after the shuffle. But I want them to be shuffled as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190649/discussion-between-tanzira-najnin-tonu-and-hoog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shuffle the last elements of each row you can go through each row independently and shuffle the last few numbers by doing the shuffle for each row, the rows will each be shuffled in different ways compared to each other, unlike what you had before where each row was shuffled the same way.

```
import numpy as np

def randomize_the_data(original_matrix, reordering_sz):
    for ln in original_matrix:
        np.random.shuffle(ln[reordering_sz:])
    print(original_matrix)

a = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
print(a)
print()
randomize_the_data(a, 2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]

[[ 0  1  4  2  3]
 [ 5  6  8  7  9]
 [10 11 13 14 12]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
```